# Guidelines for self-answered questions

Tags: discussion, self-answer

I have started to write a question. As I was writing it, as I usually do, I continue my research, and I found the answer before I finished writing the question.

Since I spent a few minutes on it, and I thought the question was both not too specific and broad enough, I thought, hey, let's try this "answer your own question, q&a style" feature.

[Double count on two tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29006768/double-count-on-two-tables)

It turns out it's very confusing to everyone. I'm not sure how to introduce my answer, so I just copied the result code without anything else. Maybe that's the issue ? Based on the comments on my answer (and the other answer), it's clear nobody understands why I answered my own question.

What am I doing wrong that makes it so confusing ?

Comment: Your answer would not meet the site standards even if it was someone else's question; we want answers to not only provide the code, but some explanation as well as to *why* it answers the question. You confused people because they didn't realise you meant that code as an answer. Sometimes new users do post part of their question in an answer post, and it looks like you maybe did so here.

Comment: @Martijn Pieters: Makes you wonder if [we really should begin considering code-only answers as unequivocally VLQ and subject to deletion](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287563/youre-doing-it-wrong-a-plea-for-sanity-in-the-low-quality-posts-queue#comment162968_287563).

Comment: Ok so based on your comment I assume the question is OK. I have added a little introduction text to my answer, but basically it only describes what the code does. Maybe I would be better off deleting my question altogether and rather post it on my blog ?

Comment: @BoltClock: I have an auto-comment for those, and a down vote (just code is not helpful).

Comment: @Martijn Pieters: I downvote on sight too. But I'm not sure if they should be taken as answers (assume good faith) or subject to deletion.

Comment: @BoltClock: they are still attempts at answering. Just, in my book, very bad attempts. They could still be helpful to someone else if they are willing to put in the extra work of figuring out why that code works.

Comment: @Martijn Pieters: lolol, someone else just posted their own code-only answer.

Comment: @BoltClock: ha! There, a demonstration opportunity of my auto-commenting skillz.

Comment: @Martijn Pieters: How do you tell if they are attempts at answering? Do you simply check if they relate to the question by context somehow? I've more than once had to delete code dumps because I couldn't figure out how they were related at all to the question other than being written in the same language.

Comment: @BoltClock: in my usual tags I can recognise when code at least tries to answer the question. If they go very far off base they'll earn a incredulous comment (*Why are you frobbing the narwhal there? That makes **no sense** in this context*). It is extremely rare for me to come across a code dump that has no relationship to the question whatsoever though (in which case it'll be a custom moderator flag for deletion).

Comment: @Martijn Pieters: Yeah, probably a case for using custom flags instead.